# The canonical form of the first Painlevé equation

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

The first Painlevé equation is traditionally written as
$$y''=6y^2+x. $$
Using scaling in both the dependent and independent variables, one can transform this equation into
$$Y''=aY^2+bx $$
for arbitrary complex constants $a,b$. My question is: is there any special reason for choosing the coefficients $a=6,b=1$ in the traditional form? If so, what is it?

My guess regarding the $a=6$ part is that this is the only choice which makes the principal part of the Laurent series expansion around any pole $x_0$ have the form
$$\frac{1}{(x-x_0)^2},$$
shared by the solutions of the Weierstrasß differential equation
$$\wp''=6\wp^2-\frac{1}{2}g_2. $$
However, I can't see any reason for preferring $b=1$ over any other value.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter $b$ would enter further along in the Laurent series at a pole. Specifically, for the equation $y'' = 6y^2 + bx$, this expansion is
$$\frac{1}{(x-x_0)^2} - \frac{b x_0}{10} (x-x_0)^2 - \frac{1}{6} (x-x_0)^3 + O\left( (x-x_0)^4 \right).$$
Since the next to leading coefficient depends on the position $x_0$ of the movable pole, one cannot use $b$ to scale away some factor in the expansion, as this would only hold at one pole. So, the plain answer is, there is no real reason to set $b=1$, and other conventions are sometimes found, such as $b=6$ or $b=-1$.
Among all equations of the form
$$y'' = 6y^2 + f(x),$$
only those obeying $f''(x) \equiv 0$ have the property that all their movable singularities are poles (Painlevé property), i.e. when $f(x) = bx + c$. It seems natural to pick $b=1, c=0$ as the canonical representative in this class, to which it can be re-scaled, unless $b=0$, in which case it is reduced to an equation with elliptic solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Painlevé's derivation in his paper: *[Mémoire sur les équations différentielles dont l’intégrale générale est uniforme](http://www.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1900__28__201_0.pdf)* Bulletin de la S. M. F., tome 28 (1900), p. 201-261.
In particular, section 14 of that paper shows how he arrives at what we now call the first Painlevé transcendent.

Chapter 14 of Ince's book, **Ordinary Differential Equations** (public domain) gives an account in English.